# Deform camera path to the shape of ground surface

Tags: modeling, camera, path

I have a landscape plane and a camera following a path. I would like to deform this path so that the camera stay a constant distance to the landscape. This is to simulate the effect from the view of a car that moves on a road. What could be a good way of doing that?

Comment: Convert the curve/path as mesh (Alt+C) then shrinkwrap it to the landscape. Apply this modifier. Convert it back to curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [shrinkwrap **constraint**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/shrinkwrap.html) on the camera with the distance set appropriately to keep it a fixed distance above the surface. If you place this constraint below the follow path constraint on the stack it should work fine. This won't deform the path itself, rather it will modify the distance above the surface that the camera is after its position is set by the path.

Comment: Uved, but FYI, the difference with the way I proposed in the comments is the camera will horizontal while moving up and down, so the camera axis won't move (looking up and down while moving up and down)

Comment: @lemon, that is true, and a good point. I didn't worry about that since the perspective of a car follows the slope. It is also fairly easily fixed with another constraint if necessary.